# Why moment.js treats dash differently from slash?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Anyone knows why:

```
moment('2022/03/30').format('L') => 03/29/2022
moment('2022-03-30').format('L') => 03/30/2022
```

Is this because of the time zone difference?

Comment: a) Moment is no longer being maintained; it might be time to find a new library; b) For a long time, [Moment docs have suggested using `moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/known-formats/), with the second string being the format, to parse dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. moment.js first checks if your string fits ISO8601 or RFC2822, then falls back to `new Date()`. '2022-03-30' is valid in ISO8601, but '2022/03/30' isn't. ISO8601 uses UTC, but `new Date()` assumes your local timezone. This means that `moment('2022-03-30')` represents 2022-03-30 at 00:00 UTC, while `moment('2022/03/30')` represents 2022-03-30 at 00:00 in your local timezone.

Regardless of what timezone its being interpreted as, its formatted in your local timezone, so because you're behind UTC it is shown as the previous day.